# How to search element in LinkedList with custom object

Tags: c#

I need to find a node with input from a customer in the linked list but I have an error CS1503. How can I solve a problem?

In this code, I create the LinkList name "customerList" to collect string data such as name, contact number, and payment from the user. After that, I need to find the contact number which input from the user to show data in the node and delete it. In code show that input in "searchCustomerDetail" cannot convert 'string' to ....

```
Error Message: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'IFN564.Customer' [IFN564]csharp(CS1503)
```

```cs
public class Customer {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
    public int[] Screening { get; set; }
    public static LinkedList<Customer> customerList = new LinkedList<Customer>();
    public static string input;

    public static void addCustomerDetail() {

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your information detail");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Full Name: ");
        string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Contact Number: ");
        string inputPhone = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Payment Method: ");
        string inputPayment = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please check your information detail!!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine($"Full Name: {inputName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Contact Number: {inputPhone}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Payment Method: {inputPayment}");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("Please 1 to confirm or 0 to cancel");
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                insert(inputName, inputPhone, inputPayment);
            break;
            case 2:
                Program.Main();
            break;
        }
        
    }

    public static void insert(string name, string phone, string payment) {

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please 1 to confirm buy ticket or 0 to cancel");
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Customer customerDetail = new Customer() {
                Name = name,
                Phone = phone,
                Payment = payment,
        };

        switch (input) {
            case 0: Program.Main(); break;
            case 1: 
                customerList.AddLast(customerDetail); 
                Program.Main();
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void searchCunstomerDetail() {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter contact number!!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Contact number: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        LinkedListNode<Customer> node = customerList.Find(input);
        Console.WriteLine(node);
    }

}
```

I try to use LinkListNode to find but It show error with input CS1503

Comment: Sorry, If you do not understand. My English skill is not strong. I will tell more detail. If you need to know to help.

Comment: please include the error message

Comment: Error Message show Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'IFN564.Customer' [IFN564]csharp(CS1503)

Comment: You cannot find a Customer object by a string. Instead try to find it by using LINQ.
`LinkedListNode<Customer> node = customerList.Where(c => c.Phone == input);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use LINQ where

```
  var node = customerList.Where(c=>c.Phone == input).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to implement IEquatable and Equals method

```
public class Guest : IEquatable<Guest>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
 
    public bool Equals(Guest other)
    {
        return Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }
}
```

then find by
`LinkedListNode<Guest> find = guestList.Find(new Guest() { Name = "John" });`

Reference: https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/06/09/using-linked-lists-in-net-with-c/

Answer (score -1):

The error is with this statement:

```cs
LinkedListNode<Customer> node = customerList.Find(input);
```

`customerList.Find` searches the `customerList` for an element (in this case, a `Customer`) that equals the argument provided to `Find` (in this case, the var, `input`). `input` is a string, not `Customer`, so it can't be used in `Find` here.

What you seemingly intend to do here is to find the `Customer` in `customerList` that has a `Customer.Phone` that equals the input string. To do so, you can use LINQ, as others have suggested:

```
LinkedListNode<Customer> node = customerList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Phone == input);
```

The above expression will find the first element in the list that returns `true` for the provided function (predicate), and will return `null` if none match.